# Tab autocompletion for a command's options

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

Tab auto-completion does not work "inside" commands, this is, for options.

For example, consider the help file of the command `mousepad`:

```
lucho@lucho-XPS15:~$ mousepad --help
Usage:
  mousepad [OPTION…] [FILES...]

Help Options:
  -h, --help               Show help options
  --help-all               Show all help options
  --help-gtk               Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  --disable-server         Do not register with the D-BUS session message bus
  -q, --quit               Quit a running Mousepad instance
  -v, --version            Print version information and exit
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
```

If I type `mousepad --disable` and then press autocomplete, nothing happens.

Why is this the case? Is there a way to enable this "extensive" tab auto-completion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this the case?

Because bash completion functions typically do not include arguments in completion.

> Is there a way to enable this "extensive" tab auto-completion?

From this [U&L post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12369/70524):

> For some commands, bash will call the command with the argument
>   `--help` and parse the output. Such commands can be registered with
>   the complete built-in, e.g. `complete -F _longopt ls`. `_longopt` is
>   in fact a completion generation function, that happens to parse a
>   command's output rather than use a fixed list. (There are other more
>   specialized completion functions that parse a command's output to
>   generate possible completions; look in `/etc/bash_completion.d/*` for
>   examples.)

So:

```
$ complete -F _longopt mousepad
$ mousepad --
--disable-server  --display=        --help            --help-all        --help-gtk        --quit            --version
```

Comment: Some commands do have this property though. `dpkg`

Comment: @luchonacho ok. So?

Comment: My question assumed none had, based on a poor exercise of induction.

Comment: How come mate terminal does it by default? In mate we got the auto completion for command AND options by default for most of the command (like "ls")

Comment: @Angel115 the terminal emulator you use has nothing to do with tab completion. The shell and the configuration for the shell does. Check what shell you were using.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Mate is using bash as default shell and bash_completion is setup by default. https://github.com/scop/bash-completion. Thanks for your hint.